# Prevent submit button from firing multiple fetch requests

Tags: javascript, fetch

I have a section on a webpage for a task :
[image]

In the form i write an email which is 'validated' later with a function.First when i submit an email which passed the validation it sends a sendSubscribe function to the server,after that i click the button unsubscribe and it sends a unsubscribeUser function.But,after that,when i click on the email input,it starts to send unsubscribe fetch requests everytime and when i click on the subscribe button it also does the same.
The network tab looks like this:
[image]

I think i know which is the problem,but i dont know how to fix it.My idea is that everytime i click on the subscribe button it ataches an event listener from the function,thats why it fires multiple unsubscribe requests.

**Subscribe functions :**  the subscribeEmail is the most important

```
import { validateEmail } from './email-validator.js'
import { unsubscribeUser } from './unsubscribeFetch.js'

export const subscribe = () => {
  const subscribeBtn = document.getElementById('subscribeButton')
  subscribeBtn.setAttribute('value', 'Unsubscribe')
  document.getElementById('emailForm').style.display = 'none'
  localStorage.setItem('isSubscribed', 'true')
  document.getElementById('submit-info').value = ''
}

export const unsubscribe = () => {
  const subscribeBtn = document.getElementById('subscribeButton')
  subscribeBtn.setAttribute('value', 'Subscribe')
  document.getElementById('emailForm').style.display = 'block'
  localStorage.setItem('isSubscribed', 'false')
}

export const subscribeEmail = (email) => {
  const isValidEmail = validateEmail(email)
  if (isValidEmail === true) {
    subscribe()
    document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      unsubscribe()
      unsubscribeUser()
      localStorage.removeItem('Email')
      e.stopPropagation()
    })
  } else if (isValidEmail === false) {
    unsubscribe()
  }
}
```

**Subscribe fetch functions:**

```
import { validateEmail } from './email-validator.js'

export const sendSubscribe = (emailInput) => {
  const isValidEmail = validateEmail(emailInput)
  if (isValidEmail === true) {
    sendData(emailInput)
  }
}

export const sendHttpRequest = (method, url, data) => {
  return fetch(url, {
    method: method,
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: data
      ? {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      : {}
  }).then(response => {
    if (response.status >= 400) {
      return response.json().then(errResData => {
        const error = new Error('Something went wrong!')
        error.data = errResData
        throw error
      })
    }
    return response.json()
  })
}

const sendData = (emailInput) => {
  sendHttpRequest('POST', 'http://localhost:8080/subscribe', {
    email: emailInput
  }).then(responseData => {
    return responseData
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err, err.data)
    window.alert(err.data.error)
  })
}
```

**Unsubscribe fetch function:**

```
export const unsubscribeUser = () => {
  fetch('http://localhost:8080/unsubscribe', { method: 'POST' }).then(response => { console.log(response.status) })
}
```

**Subscribe button event listener:**

```
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', async function (e) {
    // create a variable to store localStorage email value
    const introducedEmail = inputForm.value
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(introducedEmail)
    localStorage.setItem('Email', introducedEmail)
    subscribeEmail(introducedEmail)   //change the button style and set in local storage isSubscribed to true
    sendSubscribe(introducedEmail)  //send subscribe fetch to the server

    // prevent additional requests upon clicking on "Subscribe" and "Unsubscribe".
    if (isFetching) return // do nothing if request already made
    isFetching = true
    disableBtn()
    const response = await fetchMock()  //eslint-disable-line
    isFetching = false
    enableBtn()
  })
```

// functions for disabling the submit button when a fetch request is in progress

```
const fetchMock = () => {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve('hello'), 2000))
  }

  const disableBtn = () => {
    submitForm.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled')
    submitForm.style.opacity = '0.5'
  }
  const enableBtn = () => {
    submitForm.removeAttribute('disabled')
    submitForm.style.opacity = '1'
  }
}
```

Could you guys please help me? I have no idea how to fix this.Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is the ``isFetching`` variable declared?

Comment: What is this - const response = await fetchMock()

coz from what I understand sendSubscribe(introducedEmail) is the function that is actually hitting API if email is valid.  

The condition if (isFetching) return  isFetching = true must be before that main API call and it should await until response instead of awaiting a fetchMock ?

Correct me if I'm wrong, maybe I'm not understanding clearly.

Comment: @ Gamedroit isFetching is declared above the eventlistener for the button,i didnt include it because it looks like this :    let isFetching = false

Comment: ``if (isFetching) return;`` should be at the top of the function, the function that performs the fetch is being called before the code is interrupted.

Comment: @prograk   i included the code your asking in the question,check it. fetchMock is used basically to disable the button when a fetch request is sending,not to have the possibility to send two requests at a time

Comment: Another thing, you should study more about async functions, your function has some problems that could be easily fixed.

Comment: @Gamedroit,yes i know i should,i am continuously learning,i'm new with javascript and all this things but i do my best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So,like i said,the problem was in the function that attached a new event listener to the button,thats why unsubscribe request was sent everytime with +1  more request. So,i did this way :
Function for the submit button:

```
let isUsed = false

  const submitClickButton = async () => {
    // create a variable to store localStorage email value
    const introducedEmail = inputForm.value
    //e.preventDefault()
    console.log(introducedEmail)
    localStorage.setItem('Email', introducedEmail)
    subscribeEmail(introducedEmail)   //change the button style and set in local storage isSubscribed to true
    sendSubscribe(introducedEmail)  //send subscribe fetch to the server

    // prevent additional requests upon clicking on "Subscribe" and "Unsubscribe".
    if (isFetching) return // do nothing if request already made
    isFetching = true
    disableBtn()
    const response = await fetchMock()  //eslint-disable-line
    isFetching = false
    enableBtn()

    isUsed = true
  }

  const undoClickButton = () => {
    //e.preventDefault()
    //unsubscribeEmail()
    unsubscribeEmail()

    isUsed = false
  }

  const toggleButton = () => {
    isUsed ? undoClickButton() : submitClickButton()
  }

  submitForm.addEventListener('click', toggleButton, false)
```

And subscribeEmail function :

```
export const subscribeEmail = (email) => {
  const isValidEmail = validateEmail(email)
  if (isValidEmail === true) {
    subscribe()
    // document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    //   unsubscribe()
    //   unsubscribeUser()
    //   localStorage.removeItem('Email')
    //   e.stopPropagation()
    // })
  } else if (isValidEmail === false) {
    unsubscribe()
  }
}

export const unsubscribeEmail = () => {
 // const isValidEmail = validateEmail(email)
// if (isValidEmail===true){
    unsubscribe()
    unsubscribeUser()
    localStorage.removeItem('Email')
  //}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I modified all your functions and fixed your problem, implemented async and await.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await

**Subscribe fetch functions**

```js
import { validateEmail } from './email-validator.js'

export const sendSubscribe = async (emailInput) => {
    const isValidEmail = validateEmail(emailInput) // idk if this is async func
    if (isValidEmail === true) {
        await sendData(emailInput);
    }
}

export const sendHttpRequest = async (method, url, data) => {
  return await fetch(url, {
    method: method,
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: data
      ? {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      : {}
  }).then(response => {
    if (response.status >= 400) {
      return response.json().then(errResData => {
        const error = new Error('Something went wrong!')
        error.data = errResData
        throw error
      })
    }
    return response.json()
  })
}

const sendData = async (emailInput) => {
  await sendHttpRequest('POST', 'http://localhost:8080/subscribe', {
    email: emailInput
  }).then(responseData => {
    return responseData
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err, err.data)
    window.alert(err.data.error)
  })
}
```

**Unsubscribe fetch function**

```js
export const unsubscribeUser = async () => {
    await fetch('http://localhost:8080/unsubscribe', { method: 'POST' }).then(response => { console.log(response.status) })
}
```

**Subscribe button event listener**

```js
let isFetching = false;

document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', async function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (isFetching) return // do nothing if request already made

    // create a variable to store localStorage email value
    const introducedEmail = inputForm.value;
    
    console.log(introducedEmail);

    localStorage.setItem('Email', introducedEmail);

    // prevent additional requests upon clicking on "Subscribe" and "Unsubscribe".
    disableBtn();
    await fetchMock();
    isFetching = true;

    await subscribeEmail(introducedEmail);   //change the button style and set in local storage isSubscribed to true
    await sendSubscribe(introducedEmail);  //send subscribe fetch to the server

    // data sent, reenabling button    
    isFetching = true
    enableBtn();
});
```

// functions for disabling the submit button when a fetch request is in progress

```js
...
    const fetchMock = () => {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve('hello'), 2000))
    }

    const disableBtn = () => {
        submitForm.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled')
        submitForm.style.opacity = '0.5'
    }

    const enableBtn = () => {
        submitForm.removeAttribute('disabled')
        submitForm.style.opacity = '1'
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not working as it should do.It also sends unsubscribe requests when i click on the input field,and i can not submit another email after unsubscribe and the disable button works only at subscribe state,when the subscribe request is being sent

Comment: Oh sorry, without the complete code it's hard to test.

Comment: Can you upload your code to github? It would be easier to test and fix your code.

Comment: ,i added the github repo in the question